# how to find item in collection with $match

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have collection trusted contacts. I need to filter the document by the user. When I use method findOne I have a result, but when I use $match I got an empty array. I don't know why $match doesn't work for me.

Collection trusted contacts:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5d76008e4b98e63e58cb34cc"
    },
    "date": {
        "$date": "2019-09-09T07:32:20.174Z"
    },
    "approvedTrustedContacts": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5d764e411b7476462cf6b540"
            },
            "user": {
                "$oid": "5c5ecaf6134fc342d4b1a9d5"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5d7750af52352918f802c474"
            },
            "user": {
                "$oid": "5c64968cae53a8202c963223"
            }
        }
    ],
    "pendingApprovalContacts": [],
    "waitingForApprovalContacts": [],
    "user": {
        "$oid": "5d76008e4b98e63e58cb34cb"
    }
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5d7605f5e7179a084efa385b"
    },
    "date": {
        "$date": "2019-09-09T07:32:20.174Z"
    },
    "approvedTrustedContacts": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5d764e411b7476462cf6b541"
            },
            "user": {
                "$oid": "5d76008e4b98e63e58cb34cb"
            }
        }
    ],
    "pendingApprovalContacts": [],
    "waitingForApprovalContacts": [],
    "user": {
        "$oid": "5c5ecaf6134fc342d4b1a9d5"
    }
}
```

when I use method findOne

```
const user = await TrustedContacts.findOne({ user: "5d76008e4b98e63e58cb34cb" })
```

I have result
but when I use $match I got empty array

```
result1 = await TrustedContacts.aggregate([
        { $match: { user:  "5d76008e4b98e63e58cb34cb"  } },
      ]);
```

Comment: in aggregate you need to convert to mongoose id to match keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Works,

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

result1 = await TrustedContacts.aggregate([
    { $match: { user:  ObjectId("5d76008e4b98e63e58cb34cb")  } },
  ]);
```